# VB Linq to C# covertion error "The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have a program that I’m converting from VB to C# and have an error of “The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context” on a Linq statement. The column “Model” is a row header in “rdfcounts” table so it does exist. How do I call an actual column in the select statement?

```
var ACFTModel = (
    from rdfcounts in dc.RDFCounts
    where (Convert.ToString(rdfcounts.RDate.Value.Year) + Convert.ToString(rdfcounts.RDate.Value.Month)) == (RDFDate1.ToString())
    group rdfcounts by rdfcounts.Model into g
          select new { MonRDF = (RDFMDate.ToString() + " " + Model = g.Key + "" + Convert.ToString(g.Sum((p) => p.RDFNUm))) }).ToArray();
```

This is the Linq VB code and it does work.

```
   Dim ACFTModel = (From rdfcounts In dc.RDFCounts _
                Where (CStr(rdfcounts.RDate.Value.Year) _
                + CStr(rdfcounts.RDate.Value.Month)) = (RDFDate1.ToString) _
                        Group rdfcounts By rdfcounts.Model Into g = Group _
                        Select _
                        MonRDF = (RDFMDate.ToString + " " + Model + "" _
                        + CStr(g.Sum(Function(p) p.RDFNUm))) _
                        ).ToArray
```

Comment: What's with the `=` after the `+ Model = g.Key` in the select part?

Comment: String concatenating in VB is done with the `&` operator not the `+`.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I'm not sure what the "=" means, I'm new to C# and used a VB to C# converter and that is what is was translated to.

Comment: Replace "Model = g.Key" with "g.Key".  This was a bug in our converter - it's fixed in the next build.

Comment: @OneFineDay: Concatenation is more properly done with the '&' operator, but '+' also works, although it can be ambiguous. Basically, VB picks the operation that makes most sense for '+', which may be addition or concatenation. Part of the legacy VB mind-reading feature.

Comment: This question is not useful in its current form.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas, I get that, but since errors can occur it is best practice to advise people to use the more correct version.

Comment: @OneFineDay: Yes - I absolutely agree.

Comment: Dave, I have removed "Model" and the error cleared, but now I have an "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation" on the "where" clause. Further up in the code the converter created a "foreach (dynamic RDFDate1 in RDFDate)", I think the "dynamic" declaration is causing the error but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: This sounds like your original code used late-binding on a 'for each' variable - the C# equivalent is 'dynamic'.  However, since C# has a problem with expression trees containing a dynamic operator on the 'where' clause, just change the 'for each' variable type to the actual proper variable type (i.e., what is the type of each element in 'RDFDate'?).

Comment: Thanks Dave, I was able to change the data type and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue is this:

```
group rdfcounts by rdfcounts.Model into g
```

You're grouping by the column `Model` into the group `g`

This gives you an grouping collection, with each group having its key set to the value `rdfcounts.Model`. Essentially, this means `Model` is now found under `g.Key` in your select.

It looks like you've nearly done that, except you're trying to do a further filter `Model = g.Key` (Note C# equality is `==`, not `=`). This is guaranteed to be true since you just grouped by model (assuming `Model` was still accessible).

Long story short, replace `Model = g.Key` with `g.Key`

Comment: I have removed the "Model" identifier from the select statement and the error cleared. But I know have a new error of "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation" on the "where" clause. I think since its declared as "Foreach (dynamic RDFDate1 in RDFDate)" that might be causing the error. Any ideas? (Code is in next comment)

Comment: foreach (dynamic RDFDate1 in RDFMDate)
   {

    MAppointment apt1 = new MAppointment();
    var strOriginal = RDFDate1.Substring(4) + "/" + RDFDate1.Substring(4) + "/" + RDFDate1.Substring(0, 4);
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strOriginal);

    apt1.StartTime = dt;

    var ACFTModel = (
     from rdfcounts in dc.RDFCounts
     where (Convert.ToString(rdfcounts.RDate.Value.Year) + Convert.ToString(rdfcounts.RDate.Value.Month)) == (RDFDate1.ToString())
     group rdfcounts by rdfcounts.Model into g

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the data type on a previous array that the code was running against. Not its working correctly.

```
            RDFCountDataContext dc = new RDFCountDataContext();
        object[] ModelArray = null;
        int aptID = 0;
        aptID = 0;

        Array RDFMDate = ((
            from rdfcounts in dc.RDFCounts
            select new {Expr1 = (Convert.ToString(rdfcounts.RDate.Value.Year) + Convert.ToString(rdfcounts.RDate.Value.Month))}).Distinct()).ToArray();
```

//INSTANT C# NOTE: Commented this declaration since looping variables in 'foreach' loops are declared in the 'foreach' header in C#:

```
        foreach (String RDFDate1 in RDFMDate)
        {

            MAppointment apt1 = new MAppointment();
            //var strOriginal = RDFDate1.Substring(4) + "/" + RDFDate1.Substring(4) + "/" + RDFDate1.Substring(0, 4);
            var strOriginal = RDFDate1.Substring(4) + "/" + RDFDate1.Substring(4) + "/" + RDFDate1.Substring(0, 4);
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strOriginal);

            apt1.StartTime = dt;

            var ACFTModel = (
                from rdfcounts in dc.RDFCounts
                where (Convert.ToString(rdfcounts.RDate.Value.Year) + Convert.ToString(rdfcounts.RDate.Value.Month)) == (RDFDate1.ToString())
                group rdfcounts by rdfcounts.Model into g
                //select new { MonRDF = (RDFMDate.ToString() + " " + Model = g.Key + "" + Convert.ToString(g.Sum((p) => p.RDFNUm))) }).ToArray();
                select new { MonRDF = (RDFMDate.ToString() + " " + g.Key + "" + Convert.ToString(g.Sum((p) => p.RDFNUm))) }).ToArray();


            ModelArray = ACFTModel;
```